# Encrypting twice with same key gives back plain text

Tags: block-cipher

I read in the answer [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2314/does-encrypting-twice-using-the-same-block-cipher-produce-a-security-weakness) that when encrypting twice the plain text with same key could result in plain text as shown below

$encrypt_{key}((encrypt_{key}(plain)) = plain $

Which block-cipher algorithms are they? What is this property called in general? Is it considered weak?

Edit 1 : the question is about block ciphers, not block cipher modes of operation
Edit 2 : added more clarity to the question through an equation

Comment: You're thinking of stream ciphers, not block ciphers. A stream cipher (like [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), for example) is basically a pseudorandom number generator that produces a unique sequence of numbers for each key. These numbers are XORed with the raw data to produce an encrypted stream that can be decoded by generating the same sequence of numbers based on the same key. Repeating the XOR operations restores the original data.

Comment: @owlstead OK, I'll post as an answer instead :-)

Comment: @squeamishossifrage the above question is about block ciphers , i thought it was explicit from the question i was pointing it , anyway edited it now to make it more clear

Comment: Does [involutional (SPN) cipher](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDYQFjAD&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be%2Fpublications%2Farticle-185.pdf&ei=tpBRVLLcOYLT7QaG-IDoAw&usg=AFQjCNFhw2q8K7ES03kUPP1nTKXy9gzy3g&sig2=uAAMSTG4Zw0UZEl7_yMXog&bvm=bv.78597519,d.ZGU) fit your bill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These block ciphers are called *involutional ciphers*, after the (mathematical) [involution property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29) of a function. [This article](https://www.cosic.esat.kuleuven.be/publications/article-185.pdf) shows a cryptographic analysis of two of them: Khazad and Anubis.

Neither Khazad nor Anubis  seem to be broken at the time of writing, basically they use the same internal structure for normal block ciphers, replacing the inner components with involutional ones.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of [stream ciphers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher), not block ciphers. A stream cipher (like [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4), for example) is basically a pseudorandom number generator that produces a unique sequence of numbers for each key. These numbers are XORed with the raw data to produce an encrypted stream that can be decoded by generating the same sequence of numbers based on the same key. Repeating the XOR operations restores the original data.

Comment: the question is about block-cipher

Comment: @owlstead — Just for the record, some block ciphers have an [output feedback mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_feedback_.28OFB.29) that operates in much the same way as a stream cipher

Comment: @squeamishossifrage OK, I was still wrong footed. This is not going to answer the question, $E_k$ itself must be a block cipher that is involutional.